TypeError: Cannot read property 'mail' of null, js engine: hermes
I created a Test App to play around with sending emails from a react-native app and I keep getting this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'mail' of null, js engine: hermes

My code is very minimal and all I am trying to do is open the devices default mail application with a very basic email. I am using expo as well and I am running the app on my Iphone 13 via expo.
Here is the code:
import { Alert, Text, View, Button } from "react-native";
import Mailer from "react-native-mail";
// npm install react-native-mail --save

function sendEmail() {

  console.log(content)
  Mailer.mail(
    {
      subject: "Test",
      recipients: ["support@example.com"], // replace with your email
      body: ' Account Id: #123123',
      isHTML: true,
    },
    (error, event) => {
      Alert.alert(
        error,
        event,
        [
          { text: 'Ok', onPress: () => console.log('OK: Email Error Response') },
          { text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('CANCEL: Email Error Response') }
        ],
        { cancelable: true }
      )
    });

}


export default function Index() {

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
    >
      <Text>I hope this works</Text>
      <Button
        onPress={sendEmail}
        title="Email Me"
        color="#841584"
      />
    </View>
  );
}

Here is a sample of my package.json depedacies:
},
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "expo": "~51.0.9",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.6",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.14",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.4",
    "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.1",
    "react-native-email": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-mail": "^6.1.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10"
  },

Project Directory

Do you have any errors you can provide?

@Dom The error message is in the title and question. I improved the formatting to make it more prominent.

The error implies that Mailer isn't being exported properly from react-native-mail. But you're using it exactly as in the example in the documentation

I'm not to sure, I basically copy and pasted this from other examples I found online.

is there a way to restart the build?

Out of curiosity... does import * as Mailer from "react-native-mail"; or const Mailer = require('react-native-mail') help? Not sure what your current setup is

@Dom unfortunately it doesn't, it says the mail() function is not defined

Would you mind providing a simple setup of your directory structure? e.g.
src (directory), package.json
and the package.json contents?

@Dom I added more to the post. Hope that helps,

Hello, I did a quick googling and while the error is from a different library, I think the problem might be similar because the problem is the same: imported object from library returns null, can you check? https://github.com/angelos3lex/react-native-smtp-mailer/issues/30

@artikandri I couldn't find a solution. thank you though

Are you using ExpoGo? or the development build?
You clearly added that library and you are running an app that doesn't contain the react-native-mail library inside (probably using ExpoGo).
I would suggest you to read https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/create-a-build/
If you are actually using Development builds, so, you just need to create a new build, so the new build includes the react-native-mail code.
BTW, are you sure that library supports Expo? Seems like it doesn't: https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-mail/issues/168

I was using expo-go but I found that the problem was that react-native-mail doesn't work with Expo so I had to run the expo eject command and that solved the issue
